# Remapping of j as gj etc in .vimrc is not applied in a session

Tags: vimrc, sessions

My `.vimrc` contains:

```
noremap <buffer> <silent> $ g$
noremap <buffer> <silent> 0 g0
noremap <buffer> <silent> j gj
noremap <buffer> <silent> k gk
```

I've created a session of four windows for a particular project, and for some reason the remapping above isn't applied. The strange thing is that the above part of my `.vimrc` file is **in** the source file for the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mappings defined with `<buffer>` are only effective in the buffer that's active when they are defined. Remove `<buffer>` to have them work more-or-less everywhere. See `:help map-<buffer>` for details.